# Authentication Failure using mod_authnz_ldap with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, apache-2.4, ldap, authentication, nagios

I've set up a Nagios Core server on CentOS and I want people to be able to use their AD credentials to log into the web interface. At the moment, the httpd configuration is:

```
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Active Directory Login"
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://[servername].[domainname].inc:3268/dc=[domainname],dc=inc?sAMAccountName?sub" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN "[Username]@[domainname].inc"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "[Password]"
    Require valid-user
```

Trying to log in, though, yields this message:

```
[Thu Oct 24 15:18:13.029425 2019] [auth_basic:error] [pid 311] [client 10.121.XX.XX:52740] AH01617: user [username]: authentication failure for "/nagios/": Password Mismatch
```

I imagine I'm doing something wrong with either `AuthLDAPURL` or `AuthLDAPBindPassword`, as I'll admit I had some trouble understanding the documentation for those.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out! The issue was with `AuthLDAPBindDN`. I saw the `[username]@[domain].[TLD]` format suggested a few places, but from what I can tell it does not work. Perhaps it's for an older version of Apache.
Instead, the username should be formatted as follows:

```
CN=[username],OU=[AD folder containing username],[more entries as needed],DC=[domain],DC=[TLD]
```

Essentially, the comma-separated list is a path from the user object you're using up to the top-level domain. So if your directory structure looked like this...

```
company.com
  location1
  location2
    users
      alice
      bob
      charlie
    computers
  location3
```

...and you wanted to bind to the domain using Alice's user account, the value for `AuthLDAPBindDN` should be:

```
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=alice,OU=users,OU=location2,dc=company,dc=com"
```

Hopefully this helps anyone who is confused like I was.

Answer (score 0):

Good day !

Kindly check the cgi.cfg configuration and verify the same .

use_authentication set to 1

Comment: use_authentication is indeed set to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the update !